# Find x and y on arch

Tags: python, math, geometry

[image]

Hello all. I'm not very good with math, so I will need help writing a function in Python. There is an arch and I need to know the `x` and `y` of each pixel on the arch. All the data that I have, I have written in the picture. Let me know if anything needs to be clarified further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having arc length and radius, we can find arc angle in radians

```
fi = L/R= 366.5/350  (60 degrees, BTW)
```

Half-angle

```
hf = fi/2 = 366.5/700   (30 degrees)
```

Circle center coordinates

```
cx = R * sin(hf) = 350*1/2 = 175
cy = R * cos(hf) = 350*0.866 = 303.1
```

Now we can make loop to get pixel coordinates with given resolution with starting angle `-Pi/2-Pi/6` (in general case `-Pi/2-hf`)

```
for i in range(2220):
   an = -math.pi*2/3  +  i * 366.5/350 / 2220
   x = cx + R * math.cos(an)
   y = cy + R * math.sin(an)
```

To correct your code:

```
cx = radius * math.sin(hf)
cy = -radius * math.cos(hf)

xl.append(cx + radius * math.cos(an))
yl.append(cy - radius * math.sin(an))
```

Comment: y = cx + math.cos(an) you mean cy?

Comment: Of course, and `sin` there. Copy-paste error

Comment: can you explain this line an = -math.pi*2/3  +  i * length/radius / 2220

Comment: i * length/radius / 2220  is number of pixel multiplied by angle resolution in radians. (0.021021027 in degrees). Zero angle is right  direction (OX axis), so we have to shift angle by Pi/2 to the top point and by hf (here Pi/6=30 degrees) to arc start angle

Comment: Also add multiplication by radius